# Empty Response Body using Android Retrofit 2 Httpok3

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, httpresponse

I am using retrofit2 - httpok3 in order to communicate with Laravel 5.6 server.

I am trying to "GET" data account using http GET method.

If I do that using PostMan, all is working ok.
[image]

This are the Java classes I am using to make the android connection:

**Interface SvcApi**:

```
@GET("api/me")
public Call<JSONObject> getMe(@Query("device_id") String device_id);
```

**The Service class**

```
public class Svc {


private static SvcApi giftSvc_;



public static synchronized SvcApi initAuth(Context c) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(c);

    if (db.ExistsUser()) {

        final String token = db.findUser().getToken();

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();


        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request original = chain.request();

                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                                .build();
               
        });

       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Defaultdata.DEFAULT_IP + ":" + Defaultdata.DEFAULT_PORT + "/")
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        giftSvc_ = retrofit.create(SvcApi.class);

        return giftSvc_;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is the **method** implemented in my  Activity class in order to get the data:

```
 private void changeActivityTest(){

    svcAth = Svc.initAuth(getApplicationContext());
    Call<JSONObject> call = svcAth.getMe(Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {

            final JSONObject user = response.body();
            final Response<JSONObject> responsefinal = response;
            
            Log.e("responsefinal code", responsefinal.code() + "");
            Log.e("responsefinal message", responsefinal.message());
            Log.e("responsefinal headers", responsefinal.headers().toString());
            Log.e("responsef isSuccessful", responsefinal.isSuccessful() + "");
            Log.e("responsefinal raw", responsefinal.raw().toString());
            Log.e("responsefinal body", responsefinal.body().toString());
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Success, getMeTest Response body  = " + user.toString());
                        if(responsefinal.code() == 400){

                        }else if(responsefinal.code() == 201 || responsefinal.code() == 200){
                            Log.e("response", user.toString());
                            Log.e("e", responsefinal.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                try {
                    Log.e("error code :",response.toString() + "");
                    Log.e("error code :",response.code() + "");
                    Log.e("error:",response.message());
                    Log.v("Error ", response.errorBody().string());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(responsefinal.code() == 500|| responsefinal.code() == 503){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O serviço Voado está indisponível neste momento. Por favor, tente mais tarde.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```

The body is a empty JSONObject `{}` .

This is my **LogCat**:

```
        05-19 18:48:23.268 14659-14659/com.androidsrc.futbolin E/responsefinal code: 200
    05-19 18:48:23.268 14659-14659/com.androidsrc.futbolin E/responsefinal message: OK
    05-19 18:48:23.268 14659-14659/com.androidsrc.futbolin E/responsefinal headers: Date: Sat, 19 May 2018 21:48:22 GMT
        Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
        Vary: Authorization
        Cache-Control: no-cache, private
        X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
        X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
        Content-Length: 62
        Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Type: application/json
    05-19 18:48:23.268 14659-14659/com.androidsrc.futbolin E/responsef isSuccessful: true
    05-19 18:48:23.268 14659-14659/com.androidsrc.futbolin E/responsefinal raw: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://XXXXXXXXX:5500/api/me?device_id=c4791147feeb7e7e}
    05-19 18:48:23.268 14659-14659/com.androidsrc.futbolin E/responsefinal body: {}
```

Finally this are the version's libraries that belongs to these communications:

```
    dependencies {
     [...]
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'org.apache:apache:17'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:25.0-android'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0') {
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp peer-dependency module and define your own module import
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-protobuf:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4'
   [...]

}
```

In relation to `GsonConverterFactory` in `Retrofit.Builder()` I have tried to remove the `gson`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Defaultdata.DEFAULT_IP + ":" + Defaultdata.DEFAULT_PORT + "/")
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

And also using another `gson` implementation:

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(String.class,
                new JsonDeserializer<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                              JsonDeserializationContext context)
                            throws JsonParseException {
                        return null;
                    }
                }).create();
```

So, using Postman with the exactly the same parameters, headers and endpoint, the response is a JSONObject as you can see in the picture, but using this android implementation, the body is empty.

**EDIT**

I tried to using a pojo class:

```
public class user implements Serializable {

long id;
String first_name;
String last_name;



public user(){}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "user{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", first_name='" + first_name + '\'' +
            ", last_name='" + last_name + '\'' +

            '}';
}
}
```

But the result is the same. All the values are null:

`responsefinal body: user{id=0, first_name='null', last_name='null'}`

Comment: Why don't you try by creating  pojo class?

Comment: I did. But all the received values are null. It is why i tried to catch the response as JSONObject. This way I could see the possible differences between the response and my pojo class. But it is an empty JSONobject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah you are trying to get `JSON` from response but you are using converter I think that is not possible on that way. You need either to remove `addConverterFactory` or create `POJO` class and get values from `POJO`. For example:

```
public class MyClass {

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @SerializedName("user")
    private User user;

    private class User {

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @SerializedName("last_name")
        private String lastName;
        @SerializedName("id")
        private String id;
        @SerializedName("first_name")
        private String firstName;
    }
}
```

Replace `JSONObject` with `MyClass` and in response you will be able to `getUser()` and users info.

Comment: Using your POJO Class it works perfect. I used the pojo class showed in the EDIT part. In all my others projects that class worked perfect, but no for this one. So, thank so much. It works. Sorry about the edit. I am not able to  remove it.